# Weblogic "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown bean state 0" exception

Tags: java, weblogic, illegalargumentexception

I am investigating why the same kind of exceptions are thrown in our weblogic servers. We keep getting

**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown bean state 0**

exceptions. Mostly in peak times but it also occurs in the middle of nowhere as well. I made a research in Google about this but I could not get any answer to "Unknown bean state 0" part. I am almost sure that threads **are not stuck** because I do not have any [STUCK] label in exceptions.

Here is the exception logs:

```
####<2019-mar-28 kl 12:51 CET> <Error> <com.project-name.log.LoggerInterceptorWrapper> <abcdef.test.project-name.com> <ServerName> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '38' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <Username123test> <BEA1-4577D692FF125C4F476F> <afc37f9d-a9b3-451a-a0e2-82f719563297-000626b1> <1553773880079> <BEA-000000> <Exception in intercept 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown bean state 0
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.WLEnterpriseBeanUtils.getEJBStateAsString(WLEnterpriseBeanUtils.java:47)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseEJBContext.checkAllowedMethod(BaseEJBContext.java:78)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseEJBContext.getCallerPrincipal(BaseEJBContext.java:109)
    at com.project-name.log.LoggerInterceptorWrapper.intercept(LoggerInterceptorWrapper.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor150.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.JeeInterceptorInterceptor.invoke(JeeInterceptorInterceptor.java:109)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy237.getCustomersInfo(Unknown Source)
    at com.project-name.service.ejb.internal-service.EJBinternal-serviceCustomerBean_EJBinternal-serviceCustomerRemoteImpl.__WL_invoke(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.java:34)
    at com.project-name.service.ejb.internal-service.EJBinternal-serviceCustomerBean_EJBinternal-serviceCustomerRemoteImpl.getCustomersInfo(Unknown Source)
    at com.project-name.service.ejb.internal-service.EJBinternal-serviceCustomerBean_EJBinternal-serviceCustomerRemoteImpl_WLSkel.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.invoke(BasicServerRef.java:701)
    at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableServerRef.invoke(ClusterableServerRef.java:231)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef$1.run(BasicServerRef.java:527)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.handleRequest(BasicServerRef.java:523)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.wls.WLSExecuteRequest.run(WLSExecuteRequest.java:118)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
> 

####<2019-mar-28 kl 12:51 CET> <Info> <com.project-name.log.LoggerInterceptorWrapper> <abcdef.test.project-name.com> <ServerName> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '31' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <Username123test> <BEA1-446ED692FF125C4F476F> <f4df277f-9a33-478d-a0c1-bd9f87f26e86-0005e623> <1553773879478> <BEA-000000> <class java.lang.IllegalArgumentException Could not add request context to trans log, message Unknown bean state 0>
```

I keep getting thousands of this exceptions in peak times for different customers and for different service beans.

I am using ***Weblogic 12.1.3***

Thanks for the helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed this exception when a @Resource is used that was injected to another bean instance. For example when a @Resource is stored in some static variable and used later by the bean. This would match the observation that exception occurs at peak time, because WebLogic creates at this time additional bean instances (each with own @Resource object).

Comment: Adding an example will make answer more understandable.

Comment: @Guarav Jeswani sure

`@Stateless
public class LoggerInterceptorWrapper implements LoggerInterceptorWrapperLocal {

    @Resource SessionContext ctx;

    static SessionContext ctxCpy;

    @PostConstruct
    void postConstruct()
    {
        ctxCpy = ctx;
    }

    public void intercept()
    {
        // the call below can throw the "Unknown bean state 0" exception
        ctxCpy.getCallerPrincipal();
    }

}`

Comment: Add in your answer, not in comment.